# What is this on my ceiling?

Tags: drywall, walls, ceiling, roof, nails

1931 home. Had a few indentions that started last summer and now a few more have appeared. All in a straight line. The spots don’t seem wet but they are flexible (can push in, and if I push hard enough the ceiling moves maybe 1/8 of an inch up. How serious is this and how concerned should I be?

[image]

Comment: Do you have moisture issues in the attic? Has the original plaster been changed to drywall?

Comment: Nail dimples, maybe?

Comment: Perhaps something in the attic is resting directly on the ceiling rather than the joists and causing the drywall to sag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimples are from the nails used to hold up the drywall. Lath and plaster uses much smaller nails and would unlikely move as described without showing some cracking in the plaster.

Nails tend to back out over time or move with the seasons which can cause those dimples.

First, make sure you don't have anything sitting directly on the drywall in the attic. Then, I would add some screws in that area, make sure not to overdrive them.

Finish with some spackling paste over the screws/dimples and a touch of paint.

Comment: thank you so much! do you think this is likely to fall soon? i will get it fixed asap but my dining table is directly under it

Comment: With the description you provided, no. It still has minimal movement. I would get some drywall screws if you have access to a drill/impact driver and put a couple in or ask someone you know to assist you.

Comment: Worth adding that after you have re-secured the drywall you can cut the paper/paint with a utility knife remove the screw or push the nail back in, then go over it. Should help prevent it from "popping" back up in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Dimples are due to drywall failure around the fastener, e.g., the drywall panel dropped slightly but the fastener remained in place.  6-8 dimples per 100sf ceiling are common and need monitoring (check for leaks). Use a hand sized flat surface to push on the drywall. Movement up to 1/8 inch indicates drywall needs re-securing. Lots of dimples and/or 1/4 inch+ movement means ceiling might fall. Four common causes.

1. The hammerhead broke the drywall around the nail (didn't use a drywall hammer).
2. The drywall is water/moisture damaged, e.g., when guest shower is used or ceiling under attic in summer.
3. Insufficient or wrong type fasteners used to hold drywall.
4. Drywall is/was overloaded, e.g., stepped on while in attic.

Comment: A smidge of formatting goes a loooong way...